# 12 side dice. Roll to first odd cumulative sum. What is the most likely odd number to appear?

Tags: probability

Given a 12 sided dice, you roll the dice repeatedly until the cumulative sum is odd. What is the number of the cumulative sum you can have with the highest probability?

Comment: @DannyC It cannot be 1 as that is not sum. Roll dice up until you get a sum that is odd. what is the most likely number to occur? For Example possib. for 3 are (1,2) (2,1) and (1,1,1) for total prob of  25/1728. I was hoping for a solution that does not require one to manually compute this distribution. Very tedious for higher numbers

Comment: This shouldn't be hard to work out. The probability of requiring more than $n$ throws decreases rapidly, and you can cut off the tail after three or four throws because the probability of requiring more throws is already smaller than $\frac1{12}$, which is the probability that the first cumulative odd sum is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eleven.

For $s$ odd let $S_s$ be the set of tuples $(a_1,\ldots, a_k)$ with $k\ge 1$, $a_k\in\{1,3,5,7,9,11\}$ and all other $a_i\in\{2,4,6,8,10\}$ and $a_1+\ldots +a_k=s$. Define $|(a_1,\ldots,a_k)|:=k$.
The probability of ending at sum $s$ is
$$P(s) =\sum_{\alpha\in S_s}12^{-|\alpha|}.$$
If $s<11$ we define an injection $f\colon S_s\to S_{11}$ by
$$(a_1,\ldots,a_k)\mapsto (a_1,\ldots,a_{k-1},a_k+2)$$
(noting that $s<11$ implies $a_k<11$).
Since $(2,2,2,2,2,1)$ is not in the image of this map and $|f(\alpha)|=|\alpha|$ we conclude $P(11)>P(s)$.

If $s>11$ then observe that
$$g\colon S_s\to\bigcup_{k=1}^6S_{s-2k},\\
(a_1,\ldots,a_m)\mapsto(a_1,\ldots,a_{m-1}-1)$$
is a bijection. As $|g(\alpha)|=|\alpha|-1$, we have
$$ P(s)=\frac1{12}\sum_{k=1}^6 P(s-2k)$$
and by induction $P(s)\le \frac12P(11)$ for $s>11$.